# Search using English characters to match foreign ones

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

net MVC application using EF6
and would like searching for "O" to return matches containing "Ø"

I am using the default collation in MSSQL Server at the moment.

Do I have to change the collation or add some code?

thanks

Comment: Where do you get the idea that `Ø` has anything whatsoever to do with `O`? It's a completely separate letter, not `O` with a diacritic. This only breaks apart further as you get to more different scripts, like Azbuka or Arabic.

Comment: I think the negative votes are uncalled for. New programmers cannot know that where in real life you actually do just replace uncommon, non-native characters with the closest matching ones in your own national alphabet, there's rarely any built-in way to do the same in code where they're treated as two completely different things. @den: What might get you started, is getting a list of the characters in question and use some type of regular expression for all the characters you are expecting to be there to return "likely" matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing the collation

```
ALTER TABLE Resource ALTER COLUMN FirstName
        nvarchar(50)COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI;
```

worked

Answer (score 1):

That's called [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_Form_C).

E.g. køpenhavn could be written as

```
køpenhavn 
kopenhavn 
koepenhavn
```

So from a plain-sql you could query

```
select ...
where col1='kopenhavn' 
   or col1=replace('kopenhavn','o','ø') 
   or col1=replace('kopenhavn','o','oe')
```

or

```
select ...
where col1='kopenhavn' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI
```

(returns only 2 of 3).

The Entity Framework does support a COLLATE clause, but LINQ to SQL does not.